# Using IOption to read connectionString from config in asp.net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .net core 3.1 to read connection string using IOption but the value is coming out to be null(settings.Value.ConnectionString in the below code). Can someone help please? In the ConfigureServices of Startup, the config section is coming out fine. But not in the controller it is coming out as null.

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
  public string ConnectionString {get; set;}
}

services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(options => 
Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ABCDB").Bind(options));

public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
  private string _connectionString;
  public DefaultController(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> settings)
  {
    _connectionString = settings.Value.ConnectionString;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the approach and extract the connection string from configuration and modify the options..

```
services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(options => {
    string connectionString = Configurations.GetConnectionsString("ABCDB");
    options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
});
```

The original approach was not following binding by convention so the desired properties were not being populated.

If following a conventional approach then the model class would need to be refactored

Lets change the name for demonstration purposes.

```
public class ConnectionStrings {
    public string ABCDB { get; set; }
}
```

Using conventional approach can be done in multiple ways, as already demonstrated above, but here is another example

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configurations.GetConnectionsStrings());
```

This would be used then like

```
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase {
    private string _connectionString;
    public DefaultController(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> settings) {
        _connectionString = settings.Value.ABCDB;
    }  
}
```